# What is the difference between raise StopIteration and a return statement in generators?

Tags: python, generator, stopiteration

I'm curious about the difference between using `raise StopIteration` and a `return` statement in generators.

For example, is there any difference between these two functions?

```
def my_generator0(n):
    for i in range(n):
        yield i
        if i >= 5:
            return

def my_generator1(n):
    for i in range(n):
        yield i
        if i >= 5:
            raise StopIteration
```

I'm guessing the more "pythonic" way to do it is the second way (please correct me if I'm wrong), but as far as I can see both ways raise a `StopIteration` exception.

Comment: Explicit or implicit ('off the end') `return` is the intended way to terminate a generator.  If PEP 479 is accepted, the 'raise StopIteration' version will eventually not work as it does now.

Comment: Note that [PEP 479 "Change StopIteration handling inside generators"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0479/) was accepted into Python 3.5 in November 2014.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

There's no need to explicitly raise `StopIteration` as that's what a bare `return` statement does for a generator function - so yes they're the same. But no, just using `return` is more Pythonic.

From: http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement (valid to Python 3.2)

> In a generator function, the return statement is not allowed to include an expression_list. In that context, a bare return indicates that the generator is done and will cause StopIteration to be raised.

Or as @Bakuriu points out - the semantics of generators have changed slightly for Python 3.3, so the following is more appropriate:

> In a generator function, the return statement indicates that the generator is done and will cause StopIteration to be raised. The returned value (if any) is used as an argument to construct StopIteration and becomes the StopIteration.value attribute.

Comment: In python3 the return can have an expression-list argument: http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement

Comment: Note: if you raise a StopIteration exception explicitly in your generator there may be some methods (e.g. Python 3's multiprocessing imap_unordered()) that go on to error because they were expecting to receive a regular return (or an implicit return) and were going to raise StopIteration themselves. See @terry-jan-reedy's comment over in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14183803/what-is-the-difference-between-raise-stopiteration-and-a-return-statement-in-gen#comment42620561_14183803 for the rationale.

Answer (score 28):

As of late 2014 `return` is correct and `raise StopIteration` for ending a generator is on a depreciation schedule. See [PEP 479](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0479/) for full details.

> ## Abstract
>
> This PEP proposes a change to generators: when `StopIteration` is raised inside a generator, it is replaced with `RuntimeError`. (More precisely, this happens when the exception is about to bubble out of the generator's stack frame.) Because the change is backwards incompatible, the feature is initially introduced using a `__future__` statement.
>
> ## Acceptance
>
> This PEP was accepted by the BDFL on November 22…
>
> ## Rationale
>
> The interaction of generators and StopIteration is currently somewhat surprising, and can conceal obscure bugs. An unexpected exception should not result in subtly altered behaviour, but should cause a noisy and easily-debugged traceback. Currently, StopIteration raised accidentally inside a generator function will be interpreted as the end of the iteration by the loop construct driving the generator.
>
> …

Answer (score 5):

That's true, they are equivalent except that one is readable whereas the other is obscure. This dates back to the very first version of generators (PEP 255, under "Specification: Return"), and the subsequent enhancements of (such as coroutines) do not change this. 3.3's `yield from` (PEP 380) extends that to `return <expr>` as syntactic sugar for `raise StopIteration(<expr>)`, but that doesn't change the meaning of `return;`.