# Python - Generator case where nothing to return

Tags: python, for-loop, generator

I have a generator like so:

```
def iterate_my_objects_if_something(self):
    for x in self.my_objects:
        if x.something:
            yield x
```

Which I call like so:

```
for x in self.iterate_my_objects_if_something():
    pass
```

In the case where there is nothing to return, this tries to iterate over NoneType and throws an exception.

How do I return an empty generator instead?

Comment: Why is `my_objects` `None` when you don't have any objects? Why isn't it a list of no objects?

Comment: I think you might be misdiagnosing the problem.  You should only get this error if `self.my_objects` is `None`, not if there are no objects yielded.

Comment: you should probably post the stack trace, my bet is that the exception is being thrown _within_ the generator. All you need to do is skip the loop if you can't iterate over `self.my_objects`, or catch the exception within the generator.

Comment: Turns out I was chaining this generator in a different generator and it was throwing an error there because this one returned none. Stack trace was confusing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just do a simple check:

```
def iterate_my_objects_if_something(self):
    if self.my_objects:
        for x in self.my_objects:
            if x.something:
                yield x
```

Answer (score 5):

It is important to know, *which* iteration causes the error. That is certainly pointed in traceback, but in this case traceback is not necessary (keep reading).

### Is iteration over generator an issue?

After you take a look at that, it is obvious, but worth clarifying that:

- empty generator is not of `NoneType`, so iterating through it will not cause such issue:

  ```py
  >>> def test_generator():
      for i in []:
          yield i


  >>> list(test_generator())  # proof it is empty
  []
  >>> for x in test_generator():
      pass

  >>>
  ```
- generator is recognized by Python during definition (I am simplifying) and trying to mix generators and simple functions (eg. by using conditional, as below) will be a syntax error:

  ```
  >>> def test_generator_2(sth):
      if sth:
          for i in []:
              yield i
      else:
          return []

  SyntaxError: 'return' with argument inside generator (<pyshell#73>, line 6)
  ```

### Is the iteration *inside* generator an issue?

Based on the above the conclusion is that the error is not about iterating through iterator, but what happens when it is created (the code within generator):

```
def iterate_my_objects_if_something(self):
    for x in self.my_objects:  # <-- only iteration inside generator
        if x.something:
            yield x
```

So seemingly in some cases `self.my_objects` becomes `None`.

### Solution

To fix that issue either:

- guarantee that `self.my_objects` is always an iterable (eg. empty list `[]`), or
- check it before iteration:

  ```
  def iterate_my_objects_if_something(self):
      # checks, if value is None, otherwise assumes iterable:
      if self.my_objects is not None:
          for x in self.my_objects:
              if x.something:
                  yield x
  ```

Answer (score 3):

Check before iterating:

```
if self.my_objects:
    for x in self.my_objects:
        if x.something:
          yield x
```

Comment: Don't return `[]`. It's a generator; just drop off the end without yielding anything. This won't even compile.

Comment: @user2357112 If I do that, the same error will occur at the call site: `'NoneType' object is not iterable`

Comment: @ÓscarLópez: your code is broken, you cannot have a `return` (except the empty one) in a generator.

Comment: @user2357112 ok, fixed it then.

Answer (score 1):

This answer was answered in another question: [What is the difference between raise StopIteration and a return statement in generators?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14183803/4986615).

Basically, you just need to return None to end your generator. Raising [StopIteration is now deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30217723/4986615).

So your code can simply be:

```py
def iterate_my_objects_if_something(self):
    if self.my_objects == []:
        return
    for x in self.my_objects:
        if x.something:
            yield x
```

This is very close to the answer of this question, but it is just more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

If there is nothing to iterate throw `StopIteration` exception. See the examples below.

```
def iterate_my_objects_if_something(self):
    if not self.my_objects:
        raise StopIteration
    for x in self.my_objects:
        if x.something:
            yield x
```

I'd go even further:

```
def iterate_my_objects_if_something(self):
    if not self.my_objects:
        raise StopIteration
    yield from (x for x in self.my_objects if x.something)
```

Comment: This is decrepated: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30217723/4986615