# devide int into lower whole ints

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a random int in the range of 30-60 which I get using `randint(30,60)`. Let's say it's 40. I want to split this number in exactly 7 random whole ints. So for instance `[5,5,5,5,5,5,10]` is a valid result. But there are many possible solutions, like this one as well `[6,6,6,6,6,6,4]` or `[4,2,9,13,8,1,3]` ...
I know there are many solutions but I am searching for a fast way to go through them. I am not trying to get every single solution but rather looking for a fast way to iterate over a lot of them in short time. One way to achieve it is to randomly pick a number (let's say in the range from 1-15) and save it to a list, then do a while loop until the sum is exactly 40. I tried that and it is not efficient at all. I think choosing a start value like `[5,5,5,5,5,5,10]` and altering the numbers in a precise way like `"1st digit -2"` and `3rd +2` to yield `[3,5,7,5,5,5,10]` would be a much faster solution. Does anyone know how to do that or has a good suggestion? Thanks. I prefer python 3.

Comment: You say you are "not trying to get every single solution" but are still iterating over "a lot of them in a short time".  How many do you need to go through if not all of them?  What do you consider to be a short time?  When you find such a combination, what exactly are you doing with the data?  Knowing the answers to these questions will help narrow down potential solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If** you only care about getting an arbitrary set of numbers that add up to your total rather than an exhaustive iteration over **all** combinations, the following should get you what you need.

```
def get_parts(total, num_parts=7, max_part=15):
    running_total = 0
    for i in range(num_parts - 1):
        remaining_total = total - running_total
        upper_limit = min(max_part, remaining_total - num_parts + 1 + i)
        # need to make sure there will be enough left
        lower_limit = max(1, remaining_total - max_part*(num_parts - i - 1))
        part = randint(lower_limit, upper_limit)
        running_total += part
        yield part
    yield total - running_total

>>> list(get_parts(40))
[2, 7, 10, 11, 1, 4, 5]

>>> list(get_parts(40))
[7, 13, 11, 6, 1, 1, 1]

>>> list(get_parts(50, 4))
[6, 14, 15, 15]
```

Of course, the items in each list above is not truly random and will favor larger numbers earlier in the list and smaller numbers later.  You can feed these lists through random.shuffle() if you want more of an element of pseudorandomness.

Comment: Generating random numbers is (comparatively) _really_ slow.

Comment: Jumping between your discussion but slow compared to _what_? If he only needs one arbitrary set like this answer is designed to do, it is much faster to do with this generator than iterating over all the possibilities and then picking one of those (like in your solution).

Comment: @TeemuRisikko OP wants to iterate over "a lot" of possibilities in a "short time". Using timeit on the loop in my solution, all 4 billion iterations took 1.3 seconds on my machine to generate. Generating about 1/1000 of them with Billy's method took 73 seconds. Also, it would be pretty trivial to modify my loop to stop whenever you want, convert it to a generator, etc.

Comment: @glibdud Yes, of course. I think you just interpret the question differently. If OP really needs "a lot" of values in a short time then randomizing it would not be the best solution. Might be that your solution is closer to what OP wants.

Comment: @glibdud Hence the modifiers in my answer.  OP specifically stated "I am not trying to get every single solution."

Comment: It's a good solution but I am still wondering when I use `max_part=15` sometimes in the resulting list there can be integers that are higher than 15. Weird. Am I missing something? I want 15 to be the max value.

Comment: @Chris Since the last element in the list isn't checked against max_part, it's possible to have the last part of the list be greater than max_part in order to make the sum of all parts match the total.

Comment: @Chris:  Edited to ensure no elements will exceed the max_part.

Answer (score 4):

A set of whole numbers that sum to a number `n` is called a [partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29) of `n`; if order matters then it's called a composition.

Here's a reasonably fast way to produce random compositions.

```
import random

def random_partition(n, size):
    seq = []
    while size > 1:
        x = random.randint(1, 1 + n - size)
        seq.append(x)
        n -= x
        size -= 1
    seq.append(n)
    return seq

n = 40 
for _ in range(20):
    print(random_partition(n, 7))
```

**typical output**

```
[26, 2, 8, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[30, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2]
[26, 5, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1]
[2, 25, 9, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[28, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3]
[23, 1, 9, 3, 2, 1, 1]
[3, 26, 1, 7, 1, 1, 1]
[25, 1, 7, 1, 2, 1, 3]
[10, 8, 11, 5, 3, 1, 2]
[19, 16, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[12, 23, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 14, 15, 7, 1, 1, 1]
[29, 5, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1]
[25, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 5]
[10, 12, 10, 4, 1, 2, 1]
[13, 4, 6, 14, 1, 1, 1]
[31, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2]
[16, 11, 9, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[3, 26, 5, 3, 1, 1, 1]
[31, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1]
```

We use `1 + n - size` as the upper limit because the other `size - 1` numbers are at least 1.

Here's a fairly efficient way to generate all partitions of a given integer. Note that these are ordered; you could use `random.shuffle` if you want to produce random compositions from these partitions.

We first print all partitions of 16 of size 5, and then we count the number of partitions of 40 of size 7 (= 2738).

This code was derived from an algorithm by [Jerome Kelleher](http://jeromekelleher.net/generating-integer-partitions.html).

```
def partitionR(num, size):
    a = [0, num] + [0] * (num - 1)
    size -= 1
    k = 1
    while k > 0:
        x = a[k - 1] + 1
        y = a[k] - 1
        k -= 1
        while x <= y and k < size:
            a[k] = x
            y -= x
            k += 1
        a[k] = x + y
        if k == size:
            yield a[:k + 1]

for u in partitionR(16, 5):
    print(u)

print('- ' * 32)
print(sum(1 for _ in partitionR(40, 7)))
```

**output**

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 12]
[1, 1, 1, 2, 11]
[1, 1, 1, 3, 10]
[1, 1, 1, 4, 9]
[1, 1, 1, 5, 8]
[1, 1, 1, 6, 7]
[1, 1, 2, 2, 10]
[1, 1, 2, 3, 9]
[1, 1, 2, 4, 8]
[1, 1, 2, 5, 7]
[1, 1, 2, 6, 6]
[1, 1, 3, 3, 8]
[1, 1, 3, 4, 7]
[1, 1, 3, 5, 6]
[1, 1, 4, 4, 6]
[1, 1, 4, 5, 5]
[1, 2, 2, 2, 9]
[1, 2, 2, 3, 8]
[1, 2, 2, 4, 7]
[1, 2, 2, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 3, 3, 7]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
[1, 2, 3, 5, 5]
[1, 2, 4, 4, 5]
[1, 3, 3, 3, 6]
[1, 3, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 3, 4, 4, 4]
[2, 2, 2, 2, 8]
[2, 2, 2, 3, 7]
[2, 2, 2, 4, 6]
[2, 2, 2, 5, 5]
[2, 2, 3, 3, 6]
[2, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[2, 2, 4, 4, 4]
[2, 3, 3, 3, 5]
[2, 3, 3, 4, 4]
[3, 3, 3, 3, 4]
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
2738
```

Comment: FWIW, if you're interested in generating all compositions of a given size for a number, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40540014/4014959) I wrote.

Answer (score 1):

From [Python Integer Partitioning with given k partitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18503096/python-integer-partitioning-with-given-k-partitions)

```
def partitionfunc(n,k,l=1):
    '''n is the integer to partition, k is the length of partitions, l is the min partition element size'''
    if k < 1:
        raise StopIteration
    if k == 1:
        if n >= l:
            yield (n,)
        raise StopIteration
    for i in range(l,n//k+1):
        for result in partitionfunc(n-i,k-1,i):
            yield (i,)+result
list(partitionfunc(40,7))
```

Comment: PM 2Ring solution is more efficient though.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a simple iteration over all possible combinations of the first 6 values (where the sum does not exceed 40), and calculate the 7th value.

```
for a in range(41):
    for b in range(41-a):
        for c in range(41-(a+b)):
            for d in range(41-(a+b+c)):
                for e in range(41-(a+b+c+d)):
                    for f in range(41-(a+b+c+d+e)):
                        g = 40 - (a+b+c+d+e+f)
                        # Do what you need to do here
```

You can cut the amount of time required by the loop almost in half (according to tests using `timeit`) by precomputing the sums:

```
for a in range(41):
    for b in range(41-a):
        ab = a + b
        for c in range(41-ab):
            abc = ab + c
            for d in range(41-abc):
                abcd = abc + d
                for e in range(41-abcd):
                    abcde = abcd + e
                    for f in range(41-abcde):
                        g = 40 - (abcde + f)
                        # Do what you need to do here
```

Comment: What happens when the number of parts change from 7 to 10? 20? 2? This solution does not react to changes in specifications well.

Comment: @HaiVu I'm providing an algorithm that answers the question as asked. Parameterizing it to suit other situations should be pretty trivial for even newer Python programmers.

Comment: So, if the number of parts change to 40, then you will have nearly 40 nested for loop? I am talking about the number of parts, not the total, so it is not a trivia matter of parameterizing.

Comment: @HaiVu Yes, if you wanted 40 parts, this method would require 40 loops. It may be tedious, but it's still trivial. (And no, I don't think this would be the best method in that particular case. It doesn't intend to be.)