# All tuples of positive integers

Tags: python, combinatorics

How do I create a generator that will return tuples of all combinations of positive integers, example for generating triplets.

```
(1, 1, 1)
(2, 1, 1)
(1, 2, 1)
(1, 1, 2)
(2, 2, 1)
(2, 1, 2)
(2, 2, 2)
(3, 2, 2)
(2, 3, 2)
# and so on...
```

Comment: of all combinations of ALL positive integers?

Comment: You mean there is no limit on number of combinations ?

Comment: Specifically, OP does not want a naive combination of 3-tuples, but specifically a series [compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) of increasing value (to infinity) composed strictly of 3-tuples.

Comment: Yes, all combinations of all triplets in increasing order. I might have messed something up in my example.

Comment: What's up with the down votes?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest yes, ALL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code uses a similar approach to Paul Hankin's, but it's more general since it will generate tuples of any desired width, not just 3.

```
from itertools import combinations, count

def compositions(num, width):
    m = num - 1
    first, last = (-1,), (m,)
    for t in combinations(range(m), width - 1):
        yield tuple(v - u for u, v in zip(first + t, t + last))

def ordered_compositions(width):
    for n in count(width):
        yield from compositions(n, width)

# test

width = 3
for i, t in enumerate(ordered_compositions(width), 1):
    print(i, t)
    if i > 30:
        break
```

**output**

```
1 (1, 1, 1)
2 (1, 1, 2)
3 (1, 2, 1)
4 (2, 1, 1)
5 (1, 1, 3)
6 (1, 2, 2)
7 (1, 3, 1)
8 (2, 1, 2)
9 (2, 2, 1)
10 (3, 1, 1)
11 (1, 1, 4)
12 (1, 2, 3)
13 (1, 3, 2)
14 (1, 4, 1)
15 (2, 1, 3)
16 (2, 2, 2)
17 (2, 3, 1)
18 (3, 1, 2)
19 (3, 2, 1)
20 (4, 1, 1)
21 (1, 1, 5)
22 (1, 2, 4)
23 (1, 3, 3)
24 (1, 4, 2)
25 (1, 5, 1)
26 (2, 1, 4)
27 (2, 2, 3)
28 (2, 3, 2)
29 (2, 4, 1)
30 (3, 1, 3)
31 (3, 2, 2)
```

---

The algorithm for `compositions` was derived from the technique used for counting the number of compositions explained in the Wikipedia article on [compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28combinatorics%29#Number_of_compositions). This is essentially a variation of the well-known [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) technique.

Comment: FWIW, I recycled `compositions` from [an earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40540014/4014959) of mine.

Answer (score 2):

You can generate all tuples of positive integers by enumerating them based on their totals (total=3 first, total=4 second, total=5 third, etc.). Note that total=3 is the smallest total possible, since each element is positive, so we start with `t=3`.

Within each total, this code generates them in lexicographic order.

```
def posint():
    t = 3
    while True:
        for i in range(1, t-1):
            for j in range(1, t-i):
                    yield i, j, t-i-j
        t += 1

for i, j, k in posint():
    print(i, j, k)
```

If you want a more general version that accepts a parameter `n` describing the length of the tuples, you can enumerate tuples that sum to `t` using ["Stars and Bars"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)). This gives you non-negative tuples, but you can add one to each value to get unique positive tuples.

```
import itertools

def posint(n):
    for t in itertools.count(0):
        for c in itertools.combinations(range(t + n - 1), n - 1):
            yield [c[0]+1] + [c[i]-c[i-1] for i in range(1, len(c))] + [t+n-1-c[-1]]

for c in posint(5):
    print(c)
```

An easier-to-understand general method enumerates combinations based on their largest value, and by the first column that the value appears in. In this scheme, a result with largest value t and where t appears in the i'th column has arbitrary values less than t in the columns to the left of i, and arbitrary values less than or equal to t in the columns to the right of i.

This method is relatively easy to understand, but the order in which results come out is a bit odd.

```
import itertools

def posint(n):
    for t in itertools.count(1):
        for i in range(n):
            for c1 in itertools.product(range(1, t), repeat=i):
                for c2 in itertools.product(range(1, t+1), repeat=n-i-1):
                    yield c1 + (t,) + c2

for c in posint(3):
    print(c)
```

Comment: Nice, but can you generalize it? You've hard-coded two loops; can you rewrite it to accept the desired length of the output tuples as a parameter?

Comment: @Aran-Fey yes, but it makes the code a little harder to understand. I added it to my answer as an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

This is a brute-force method which assumes no ordering requirement.

**Warning**: Using `set` via `toolz.unique` as here to remove duplicates is memory-intensive and expensive. There are better ways.

```
from itertools import count, product, chain
from toolz import unique

def gen_tups(n):
    yield from unique(chain.from_iterable(product(range(1, c), repeat=n) \
                      for c in count(start=2))):

x = gen_tups(3)

next(x)  # (1, 1, 1)
next(x)  # (1, 1, 2)
next(x)  # (1, 2, 1)
```

Note `toolz.unique` implements this [commonly used recipe](http://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/toolz/itertoolz.html#unique), so you do not need access to the 3rd party library.