# Print all possible distribution of sums of n into m spaces

Tags: python, algorithm, permutation

For example, wanting a sum of 3 into 4 spaces would be:

```
3 0 0 0, 
0 3 0 0,
0 0 3 0,
0 0 0 3,
0 1 1 1,
1 0 1 1,
1 1 0 1,
1 1 1 0,
2 1 0 0,
...
```

or sum of 3 into 2 spaces would be:

```
2 1
1 2
0 3
3 0
```

Comment: Hm... That's an algorithical problem, not a python-specific

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sequences you are looking for are called [compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)).

Finding a composition of a number *n* is equivalent to selecting indices in an interval from 0 to *n*. You recover the composition by getting the distance between consecutive selected indices.

#### Example

Given the number *n = 3*, we want a composition of length *4*.

The first two indices *must* be *0* and *3* since this is our range. We then select three more indices in the interval *[0, 1, 2, 3]* to produce exactly *4* gaps.

```
[0, 1, 2, 3]
 ^     ^  ^
       ^  ^
```

We thus selected *0, 2, 2, 3, 3*. We recover the composition by getting the distance between consecutive indices. That is *[2, 0, 1, 0]*.

This corresponds to taking a combination with replacement of numbers from *0 to 3*. We can thus use `itertools.combinations_with_replacement` and translate each such combination into the corresponding composition.

### Code

```
def compositions(sum_, n):
    for indices in combinations_with_replacement(range(sum_ + 1), n - 1):
        yield [b - a for a, b in zip([0, *indices], [*indices, sum_])]

print(*compositions(3, 4))
```

### Output

```
[0, 0, 0, 3]
[0, 0, 1, 2]
[0, 0, 2, 1]
[0, 0, 3, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 2]
[0, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 2, 0]
[0, 2, 0, 1]
[0, 2, 1, 0]
[0, 3, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 2]
[1, 0, 1, 1]
[1, 0, 2, 0]
[1, 1, 0, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 0]
[1, 2, 0, 0]
[2, 0, 0, 1]
[2, 0, 1, 0]
[2, 1, 0, 0]
[3, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Oooo now this I like over your first response, alot... this is pretty

Comment: Glad you do! I even added some explanation of the mechanic behind it

Comment: I don't understand where the 'implicit' index 4 comes into play. It is never selected, and the distance to it is never used.

Comment: @m69 You might want to refresh, I originally made a mistake in the explanation

Comment: You may enjoy my partition code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40220262/4014959), and check out the linked article by Jerome Kelleher.

Answer (score 1):

Using `itertools.product` and `filter` create all the possibilities and then filter the ones whose sum is `3`

```
from itertools import product

lst = [0, 1, 2, 3]
print(list(filter(lambda x: sum(x) == 3, product(lst, repeat = 4))))
print(list(filter(lambda x: sum(x) == 3, product(lst, repeat = 2))))
```

Comment: Although, this traveses *a lot* of combinations that do not sum to 3

Comment: @OlivierMelançon I know and Martijn said something to me about a similar problem, the thought kept popping up in my head, how would work around that fact?

Comment: I actually figured out the correct abstraction, you must use combinations with replacements to iter over exactly the partitions you want. See my answer