# Unable to understand slices of variable of for loop

Tags: python, loops, slice

Recently, I found a piece of python code posted by Paul Panzer (the best answer) in [Python "Stars and Bars"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53561814/python-stars-and-bars)

```
import itertools
bars = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8]
result = [[bars[j+1] - bars[j] - 1 for j in range(5)] for bars[1:-1] in itertools.combinations(range(1, 8), 4)]
```

I couldn't understand the slices of variable `bars[1:-1]` inside the for loop. Please help.

What is the relationship bewteen `bars` and the member of the iterable object in the loop?

Comment: Please, explain more clearly "What is the relationship bewteen bars and the member of the iterable object in the loop?"

Comment: Within my comperhension of loop in python, the variable after the `for` keywoard will be assigned to each member of the iterable object during the iteration. My question is the relationship the already defined variable `bars` and the loop variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the expression:

```
for foo in itertools.combinations(range(1, 8), 4)
```

`itertools.combinations(range(1, 8), 4)` is yielding sequences of 4 items, which are being assigned to the variable `foo`.  You can see this if you just print `foo` in a loop:

```
>>> for foo in itertools.combinations(range(1, 8), 4):
...     print(foo)
...
(1, 2, 3, 4)
(1, 2, 3, 5)
(1, 2, 3, 6)
(1, 2, 3, 7)
(1, 2, 4, 5)
(1, 2, 4, 6)
(1, 2, 4, 7)
(1, 2, 5, 6)
(1, 2, 5, 7)
(1, 2, 6, 7)
(1, 3, 4, 5)
(1, 3, 4, 6)
(1, 3, 4, 7)
(1, 3, 5, 6)
(1, 3, 5, 7)
(1, 3, 6, 7)
(1, 4, 5, 6)
(1, 4, 5, 7)
(1, 4, 6, 7)
(1, 5, 6, 7)
(2, 3, 4, 5)
(2, 3, 4, 6)
(2, 3, 4, 7)
(2, 3, 5, 6)
(2, 3, 5, 7)
(2, 3, 6, 7)
(2, 4, 5, 6)
(2, 4, 5, 7)
(2, 4, 6, 7)
(2, 5, 6, 7)
(3, 4, 5, 6)
(3, 4, 5, 7)
(3, 4, 6, 7)
(3, 5, 6, 7)
(4, 5, 6, 7)
```

If you replace `foo` with a list slice that is 4 elements long, then those 4 elements are instead assigned to that slice:

```
>>> bars = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8]
>>> for bars[1:-1] in itertools.combinations(range(1, 8), 4):
...     print(bars)
...
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 8]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 8]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 7, 8]
[0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 8]
[0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 8]
[0, 1, 2, 4, 7, 8]
[0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 8]
[0, 1, 2, 5, 7, 8]
[0, 1, 2, 6, 7, 8]
[0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 8]
[0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 8]
[0, 1, 3, 4, 7, 8]
[0, 1, 3, 5, 6, 8]
[0, 1, 3, 5, 7, 8]
[0, 1, 3, 6, 7, 8]
[0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 8]
[0, 1, 4, 5, 7, 8]
[0, 1, 4, 6, 7, 8]
[0, 1, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8]
[0, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8]
[0, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8]
[0, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8]
[0, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8]
[0, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8]
[0, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8]
[0, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8]
[0, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8]
[0, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8]
[0, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8]
[0, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8]
[0, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Same 4 elements, but now they're assigned to the middle of `bars`, as referenced by the slice expression `bars[1:-1]`.

In the context of your comprehension, `bars` will have those values as it goes through the outer loop.  The inner comprehension generates another list that is based on the value of `bars` in that outer loop.

Comment: Thanks, I can vaguely understand the procedure from the output of which you presented. But, is there any document may related to this?

Comment: And I also found that if using line compression for the second piece of code, which is `[bars for bars[1:-1] in itertools.combinations(range(1, 8), 4)]`, the output will be a list contain 35 repeated `[0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`. Could you explain it to me?

Answer (score 0):

`bars[1:-1]` basically means all the list items from index `1` to `-1`, where `-1` means the last index.

So if `bars = [1,2,3,4,5]`, `bars[1:-1] = [2,3,4]`