# to find unequal partitions of an integer in php

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have total partitions of an integer and I want only those partitions which have all the values unequal.

For ex.

-`Partitions of 3 are {1,1,1,1},{2,2},{3,1},{1,1,2} and {4}.`

So, the required unequal partitions are `{3,1}` and `{4}` because they contain no equal elements.I can filter the partitions to get the desired result, but I want some efficient way to find all the partitions, which have no equal terms in them, without finding all the partitions. I have searched the net and StackOverflow but nothing states exactly the problem that I am facing. Every idea is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: what have you tried? please post sample code to improve your post

Comment: I think your example shows the partitioning of 4 and not of 3.

Comment: Your title says "in php", but your tags say "python". Which do you want?

Answer (score 1):

I would just use sets for this:

```
partitions = [[1,1,1,1], [2,2], [3,1], [1,1,2], [4]]

unique_partions = [p for p in partitions if len(p) == len(set(p))]
```

Comment: He wants to make it fast by directly filtering the ones with equal values in it before finishing the whole patritioning.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you want to have speed, right?

I guess the speed comes from the best possible partitioning algorithm **with memorization** instead of just any partitioning with pre-abortion in case of equal numbers.

If you search on stackoverflow, you'll find plenty of good ones, e.g.:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44209393/701049 (including a benchmark)
or
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18503368/701049 (from his EDIT).

I'd combine such a good one with the filter provided by Turn. 
If you want even more speed, you could also try to return None from the function in case of same numbers, and/or to write the partitioning in C-Code and compile it.

Combined it could look like this (accel_asc() copied from the link):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def accel_asc(n):
    a = [0 for i in range(n + 1)]
    k = 1
    y = n - 1
    while k != 0:
        x = a[k - 1] + 1
        k -= 1
        while 2 * x <= y:
            a[k] = x
            y -= x
            k += 1
        l = k + 1
        while x <= y:
            a[k] = x
            a[l] = y
            yield a[:k + 2]
            x += 1
            y -= 1
        a[k] = x + y
        y = x + y - 1
        yield a[:k + 1]

N = 20
unequal_partitions = [p for p in accel_asc(N) if len(p) == len(set(p))]
print unequal_partitions
```

You could also try to compile using Cython to make it even faster.