# Combination function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, combinations

I want to write a function which gives me a combination of numbers (with the given number of them) as a coefficients, that sum of them gives us 4.

Let's say the given variable number is 2. So we need to say find combination of `a+b=4`. It'll be `[1,3], [2,2], [3,1], [0,4], [4,0]`. Or if the given variable number is 3, so need to find combination of `a+b+c=4` which will be `[1,2,1], [1,1,2]`, etc.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are trying to solve is referred in Number Theory as [Integer Partitioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29). Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18503096/python-integer-partitioning-with-given-k-partitions) for a possible solution. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217597/number-of-ways-to-write-n-as-a-sum-of-k-nonnegative-integers) math exchange might also help you to understand more about the math behind the problem.

Answer (score -2):

You can use this code

```
def combinations(iterable, r):
# combinations('ABCD', 2) --> AB AC AD BC BD CD
# combinations(range(4), 3) --> 012 013 023 123
pool = tuple(iterable)
n = len(pool)
if r > n:
    return
indices = list(range(r))
yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
while True:
    for i in reversed(range(r)):
        if indices[i] != i + n - r:
            break
    else:
        return
    indices[i] += 1
    for j in range(i+1, r):
        indices[j] = indices[j-1] + 1
    yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! And How can I check if their sum is 4 or not?

Comment: (1) This code is just taken from https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations without proper attribution (2) it's not formatted correctly (3) it doesn't solve the problem asked for in the question