# all possible combinations of calculation math

Tags: combinatorics

I'm looking for a script that could tell me all possible combinations

```
input   (9)
output  (8+1)(7+2)(6+3)(5+4)(9)

input   (10)
output  (9+1)(8+2)(7+3)(6+4)(5+5)(10)
```

I would still appreciate the ability to select as many digits as possible
in the example it is 2 to 1 (even if only two is enough)
something this way

there should be an exit at three

```
input   (10)
output  (7+1+2)(6+3+1)(5+4+1)(4+4+2)(3+6+2)(1+6+3)
```

here is at least part of the possible results

I'm a beginner and the only thing I can do is combine all the words but this is at another level thank you for your help

```
word = ""
word_array = []
for c in word:
    word_array.append(c)
import itertools
results = list(itertools.permutations(word_array))
o = ""
for r in results:
    o += "".join(r)+"\r\n"
    print("".join(r))
f = open(""+str(word)+".txt", "a")
f.write(o)
f.close()
exit()
```

Comment: It's not really at another level.  Just create your array with the numbers up through your target (`list(range(1,N+1))`).  You don't want `permutations`, you want `itertools.combinations`.  You can call it once for all combos of 2, and once for all combos of 3.  It's not really that hard -- give it a try.

Comment: @TimRoberts I'm new to programming and that's beyond me
started here recently python could i ask for a code?

Comment: @TimRoberts unfortunately I can't advise you, it's too complicated for me

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18503096/python-integer-partitioning-with-given-k-partitions) (Python-specific) or [this language-agnostic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400794/generating-the-partitions-of-a-number) post answer your question?

Comment: @kcsquared  yes partially yes they still need a limit on the number of numbers I enter  sometimes it will be 2 and sometimes 3 sometimes more

Comment: The Python-based post specifically asks for the case where you specify the size of the partitions. Unless you mean something different by 'number of numbers', that appears to be what you're asking for.

Comment: `def part(n, k):
    def _part(n, k, pre):
        if n <= 0:
            return []
        if k == 1:
            if n <= pre:
                return [[n]]
            return []
        ret = []
        for i in range(min(pre, n), 0, -1):
            ret += [[i] + sub for sub in _part(n-i, k-1, i)]
        return ret
    return _part(n, k, n)

print(part(5, 2))`  this thanx for solved