# Number of integer partitioning into exactly k parts (calculating for large integer )

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, integer-partition

Following this thread [python-integer-partitioning-with-given-k-partitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18503096/python-integer-partitioning-with-given-k-partitions)

I want to find the ***number*** of such partitions (where the minimum part is equal to 1), but the following solution (in the thread and many other threads) gives the exact partitions of such an integer into k parts.

Since the algorithm is recursive and gives each partition I thought it might help me to just count the number of such partitions with memoization or dynamic programming, but I couldn't come up with a good solution.

So for example for `n=7` and `k=2` the result will be `res=3` intead of `res=[[1,6],[2,5],[3,4]]`

Comment: Would the solution where order matters help? E.g., for n=7, k=2 it would give 6 b/c it would include res=[[1,6],[2,5],[3,4],[4,3],[5,2],[6,1]]. If useful, this could be found quickly.

Comment: It does answer the question but it uses a recursive solution (though can be converted to for loop), but I think the formula from Mathematica helped me solve this problem better.

Dave: 
the sequence must be in increasing order (If the order doesn't matter it just a combinatorics question)

Answer (score 1):

After consulting the thread in Mathematica [Integer partition of n into k parts recurrence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1908701/integer-partition-of-n-into-k-parts-recurrence), came up with the following solution:

```
def p(n: int, k: int) -> int:
   memo: list[list[int]] = [[0 for _ in range(k+1)] for _ in range(n + 1)]
   for i in range(1,n + 1):
       memo[i][1] = 1

   for i in range(2,n + 1):
       for j in range(2, k+1):
           memo[i][j] += memo[i-1][j - 1]
           if i - j >= j :
               memo[i][j] += memo[i - j][j]

   return memo[n][k]
```