# Is there a "join" like function for generic lists in Python?

Tags: python

In Python, a list of strings can be joined together by

```
','.join(['ab', 'c', 'def'])
```

But how could I easily join a list of numbers or some other things? Like this:

```
0.join([1, 2, 3])  --->  [1, 0, 2, 0, 3]
```

Now I have to do this:

```
sum([[x, 0] for x in [1, 2, 3]], [])[:-1]
```

Comment: Short answer: Nope.

Comment: Note that what you're describing is a different operation: `str.join` turns a list-of-strings into a string by interleaving and concatenating, your generalized join would turn a list-of-x into a list-of-x by only interleaving and not concatenating. The concatenation part is the whole reason `join` is a string method instead of a list method.

Comment: You probably want `[0].join([[1,2,3], [4,5], [6,7,8]])` to represent the same function.

Comment: As a note - your example code uses `sum()` to join lists - this is generally a really bad idea as `sum()` isn't optimised for the task. Take a look at RemcoGerlich's generator for the best way to do this. For a general case of joining many lists - you want [`itertools.chain()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) (use `list()` on the resuling generator if you need a list).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could make one:

```
def join_generator(joiner, iterable):
    i = iter(iterable)
    yield next(i)  # First value, or StopIteration

    while True:
       # Once next() raises StopIteration, that will stop this
       # generator too.
       next_value = next(i)
       yield joiner
       yield next_value

joined = list(join_generator(0, [1, 2, 3, 4]))
```

Comment: Note you could just do `yield next(i)` initially (before entering the `while` loop), no need to assign to `next_value` - other than that, a nice implementation.

Comment: Pah! We need more one-liners! Everybody loves one-liners! `itertools.islice(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.izip(itertools.repeat(joiner), iterable)), 1, None)`

Comment: @DominicKexel And this isn't a separate answer because?  It's sufficiently different from he posted answer.

Comment: Semantics of StopIteration changed around Python 3.3. See 
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/14183847/2160256. So the above answer does no longer work but is trivially modifyable: just wrap the `next` calls into try/except and return in case of exception.

Answer (score 2):

Just because everybody loves unreadable one-liners:

```
import itertools

def join(sep, col):
    return itertools.islice(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.izip(itertools.repeat(sep), col)), 1, None)
```

P.S.: better use [RemcoGerlich's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22788218/142637). It's way more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Not the way you are wanting to do it. You could write a for loop for the sum or you could write a for loop and have each item added as you go through your list. Otherwise, you won't be able to make the adjustment you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone is telling you, join is a string method instead of a list method.

But you can always do:

```
[int(x) for x in '0'.join(map(str, [1, 2, 3]))]
```

Comment: Hmm, that relies on the assumption that all numbers are single digit?

Comment: Not bad. But if the element is float or so, it can loose precision.

Comment: Yep, relies in a lot of assumptions, but does what he wants to

Comment: @tomaspdc I'm pretty sure that the scenario given is a simplified one - assuming single digit seems unlikely to be a real case. The original poster also says 'or some other things'.

Comment: I agree, if you want a generalized use I like @RemcoGerlich solution more.

Answer (score 0):

For newer python versions the following should do

```
def join(joiner, iterable):
    """Small helper that does similar things as "foo".join("bar") """
    it = iter(iterable)
    head, tail = next(it, None), it
    if head is not None:
        yield head

    for item in tail:
        yield joiner
        yield item


assert list(join("a", range(4))) == [0, "a", 1, "a", 2, "a", 3]
assert list(join("a", [])) == []
assert list(join("a", [0])) == [0]
```

Did I miss some corner case?