# How to merge elements together in a list that are separated by ' / ' on both sides?

Tags: python, list, function, element

Its hard for me to explain this accurate, but what i want is this.
The numbers between the elements containing the string '/' merged together like so:

```
source = ['3', '/', '7', '/', '1', '1', '/', '1', '5', '/', '2', '2', '/', '1', '1', '5']
```

some function....

```
output = ['3', '/', '7', '/', '11', '/', '15', '/', '22', '/', '115']
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: See itertools.groupby

Comment: You should start with ‘’.join(source).split(‘/‘) and then You need something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22788055/is-there-a-join-like-function-for-generic-lists-in-python

Answer (score 1):

You could try iterating through the list and keeping a tracker. When you reach a number, add it to the tracker; when you reach a /, reset and add the tracker to the list.

```
def merge(arr):
    ret = []
    el = ''
    for i in arr:
        if i == '/':
            ret.extend([el, '/'])
            el = ''
        else:
            el += i
    ret.append(el)
    return ret

>>> merge(['3', '/', '7', '/', '1', '1', '/', '1', '5', '/', '2', '2', '/', '1', '1', '5'])
['3', '/', '7', '/', '11', '/', '15', '/', '22', '/', '115']
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Will spend some time to fully understand what is going on in the function, and implement it in my program.

Answer (score 1):

```
def merge(source, separator):
  lst = ''.join(source).split(separator)  # join lists then split on separator
  result = [separator] * (len(lst) * 2 - 1)  # inject separator between each item
  result[0::2] = lst
  return result

source = ['3', '/', '7', '/', '1', '1', '/', '1', '5', '/', '2', '2', '/', '1', '1', '5']
print(merge(source, '/')) # ['3', '/', '7', '/', '11', '/', '15', '/', '22', '/', '115']
```

Answer (score 0):

Same idea with slightly different implementation:

```
def func(input):
    ret = []
    i = 0
    curr_grp = []

    while i < len(input):
        if input[i] != '/':
            curr_grp.append(input[i])
        else:
            ret.append(''.join(curr_grp))
            ret.append('/')
            curr_grp = []
        i += 1

    return ret
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) function like this:

```
from itertools import groupby

separator = '/'
source = ['3', '/', '7', '/', '1', '1', '/', '1', '5', '/', '2', '2', '/', '1', '1', '5']

result = []
for blend, chars in groupby(source, lambda v: v != separator):
    result.append(''.join(chars) if blend else separator)

print(result)  # -> ['3', '/', '7', '/', '11', '/', '15', '/', '22', '/', '115']
```