# Emulating yield with a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, yield

I have the following `yield` function:

```
def yield_numbers(start=1, end=1e6):
    num = start
    while num <= end:
        yield num
        num += 1
```

I would like to build a class to replicate the most basic functionality of the `yield` expression to understand how it works a bit more. Here is what I have so far:

```
class YieldNumbers:
    def __init__(self, start=1, end=1e6):
        self.start = int(start)
        self.end = int(end)
        self._current_val = None
        self._closed = False
    def __iter__(self):
        if self._closed: raise StopIteration
        return self
    def close(self):
        self._closed = True
    def send(self, value):
        return self.__next__(value)
    def throw(self, exc_type):
        assert isinstance(exc_type, Exception)
        return self.__next__(exc_type=exc_type)
    def __next__(self, value=None, exc_type=None):
        if self._closed: raise StopIteration
        if exc_type: raise exc_type
        self._current_val = value if value else self.start if not self._current_val else self._current_val + 1
        if self._current_val > self.end: self._closed=True; raise StopIteration
        return self._current_val
```

And using it:

```
for i in YieldNumbers(start=1,end=3):
    print (i)
1
2 
3
>>> y=YieldNumbers()
>>> next(y)
1
>>> y.close()
>>> next(y)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 18, in __next__
StopIteration
```

Is this similar to how `yield` works (at its most basic level). If not, what am I missing here? Again, this isn't to re-invent the wheel or to make something robust, it's more to understand how yield works at a conceptual level.

Comment: This question might be useful to look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14183803/what-is-the-difference-between-raise-stopiteration-and-a-return-statement-in-gen

Comment: It honestly looks like an extremely good implementation of the iterator protocol. Maybe you could slightly improve it by making it more general by, for example, coding having a counter 'n' which increases every time __next __ is called and having __next __ so that, if 'n' is greater than the ending value, you raise the StopIteration, otherwise you use a function to generate the associated value. For this specific implementation though it's practically perfect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the behaviour is the same in your example, this is not similar to how `yield` works. Fundamentally, `yield` pauses the execution of a generator function, and it resumes from the same place when `next` is called; and the generator function *begins paused*, so the initial code is not executed until the first call to `next`.

It is possible, but non-trivial to transform code using `yield` into code which doesn't use `yield`. To simulate the way that the generator works, we need the instance to know where it should pretend to "resume" from, so let's call that `resume_point`. I didn't bother with some details like sending data back to the generator, exception handling, or closing; but you get the idea.

```py
class Example:
    def __init__(self, start, end):
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
        self.resume_point = 0
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def __next__(self):
        if self.resume_point == 0:
            # simulates the beginning of your generator function
            self.num = self.start
            # simulates checking the `while` loop condition
            if self.num <= self.end:
                # next time we should continue from the `yield`
                self.resume_point = 1
                # `return` simulates pausing the generator function
                return self.num
            # simulates the end of your generator function
            self.resume_point = 2
            raise StopIteration
        elif self.resume_point == 1:
            # simulates continuing from the `yield` in your generator function
            self.num += 1
            # simulates checking the `while` loop condition
            if self.num <= self.end:
                # redundant, but it shows what happens
                self.resume_point = 1
                # `return` simulates pausing the generator function
                return self.num
            # simulates the end of your generator function
            self.resume_point = 2
            raise StopIteration
        elif self.resume_point == 2:
            # simulates resuming from after your generator function returned
            self.resume_point = 2
            raise StopIteration
```

Comment: just to clarify -- "0" would mean the start of the generator, "1" would mean during the active execution, and "2" would mean when it exits, correct?

Comment: In this example, yes, 0 is the start of the function, 1 is the `yield`, and 2 is the end. There could be more resumption points for different examples, generally one per `yield`.